# Sending data from component to component

Tags: vue.js

Why does it end up outputting an empty array? I tried all versions...

**Main.vue**

```html
<template>
  <List :info="JSON.stringify({ info })"></List>
</template>

<script>
   import List from './List.vue'
   export default{
       data(){
          return {
              info: {}
          }
       },
       components: {
          List
       },
       created(){
          this.info = {'first': '1'}
       }
</script>
```

file when 'console.log' should show {'first': '1'}

**List.vue**

```js
export default{
   data(){
      return {}
   },
   props: ['info'],
   created(){
      console.log(this.info)
   }
```

Comment: reactivity is lost if you use methods like that. you could maybe implement an watcher inside your component that watches whenever your prop changes and then stringify it

Comment: Absolutely nothing in this should produce an empty array. There are no arrays at all.

Comment: Can't reproduce this at all ~ https://jsfiddle.net/mxsL8gob/. In the Fiddle, you can see that `{"info":{"first":"1"}}` is logged

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reactivity is lost if you use methods like that. Here an solution with watchers that should work. You watch your prop for changes and stringify your output then

```
<template>
  <List :info="info"></List>
</template>

<script>
   import List from './List.vue'
   export default{
       data(){
          return {
              info: {}
          }
       },
       components: {
          List
       },
       created(){
          this.info = {'first': '1'}
       }
</script>
```

Now the watcher:

```
export default{
   data(){
      return {}
   },
   props: ['info'],
   watch: {
      info: {
         handler(val) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(val))
         },
         deep: true
      }
      
   }
}
```